# Javascript Changing Table Values

Tags: javascript, html

Having trouble figuring out why I can't change a table value.

```
function StartGame() {
  document.getElementById("Player1").value = document.getElementById("Name1").value;
  document.getElementById("Player2").value = document.getElementById("Name2").value;
  document.getElementById("Player3").value = document.getElementById("Name3").value;
}
```

Link to JsFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/steventang166/q1upgdw0/10/

Comment: can you include the html table code

Comment: Sure, how do I send it so it's not messy?

Comment: just include what is needed, name1-3 and player1-3, or if that is too much just do one of each, another option is to create a jsfiddle with your code in

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/steventang166/q1upgdw0/

Comment: Please edit the question and include the code there (using the "js snippet tool"), so readers won't have to visit other sites to view the code.

Comment: Ok, but the question has already been solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`th` does not have value property. It has an innerHTML though:

```
function StartGame() {
    document.getElementById("Player1").innerHTML = document.getElementById("Name1").value;
    document.getElementById("Player2").innerHTML = document.getElementById("Name2").value;
    document.getElementById("Player3").innerHTML = document.getElementById("Name3").value;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q1upgdw0/4/

Answer (score 0):

`value` is only applicable to form control elements, not content flow ones

Change:

```
document.getElementById("Player1").value = document.getElementById("Name1").value;
```

To:

```
document.getElementById("Player1").innerHTML = document.getElementById("Name1").value;
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/q1upgdw0/2/)**</kbd>